# How to full outer join multiple csv files into a single data.table in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, join, data.table

I have been using python for a while now to work with pandas dataframes. I want to switch the same code I am using over to R. However, I don't have much experience with R and I'm not sure what options I have to do the same thing. I have a folder of many csv files, and I have a list of the file names which I would like to iterate over and do a full outer join of the files.

In pandas, I would run the following command,

```
import pandas as pd
filelist = pd.read_excel("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/list.xlsx") #contains a list of filenames in the File column around 8000 rows long

workingdf = pd.DataFrame() #create a blank data frame

for subdir in filelist.File:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/{subdir}",index_col=0) #open file 2 columns named DATE and VALUE
    df = df.rename(columns={"VALUE":subdir}) #rename the value column to the file name
    workingdf = pd.merge(workingdf,df,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

The last part of the code merges all the dataframes in the dictionary into one big data frame using a full outer join.

I want to take a bunch of csv files I have in a folder, iterate over a list of file names, create data tables out of the files, and append them one by one to make one big data table in R.

I am trying to switch to R because I am running into memory and efficiency problems and someone suggested I give it a try.

How can I run the same instruction set in R? I don't have much experience with it but I have the following code so far.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(data.table)

filelist <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/list.xlsx")


for (row in filelist[1]){

}
```

I know I need to use `tempdf = read.csv(paste("/Users/XXX/Documents/test/data/",row,sep""))` to create the path to the file and make the frame.

The renaming function should be along the lines of `names(tempdf)[2]<-row`

I also know that I have to use `workingdf <- merge(workingdf,tempdf,by="DATE",all=TRUE)`

But I don't really know where to start on this because I can't create a blank dataframe like in pandas and just start merging them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/11437205

Comment: what if I want to use my own list of file names?

Comment: and i think this code appends row-wise, I would like to do a full outer join column wise

Answer (score 2):

An example of full outer join on a list of csvs

```
library(data.table)
#get list of csv in current folder
l <- list.files(pattern="(.*).csv")

#use data.table::fread to read them and then merge with all=TRUE for full outer join
#Reduce is a recursive function takes prev output to be merged with next input
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="DATE", all=TRUE), lapply(l, fread))
```

Comment: What if I want to provide it my own list ?

Comment: then replace `l` with your list

Comment: If I use read.xlsx will the format be the same? the file names need to be concatenated with the directory

Comment: i do not know how your spreadsheet looks like. You can use `full.names=TRUE` argument for the full path. give it a try and see what other problems you have since we are unable to help if we dont have your data

Comment: there is a WIP PR https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4370 that proposes api `mergelist(l, on="DATE", how="full")`

Answer (score 1):

One can use R functions such as `paste0()` or `sprintf()` to build the full path file name for a list of files to be read into R. Here is an example that downloads spreadsheets for the first seven generations of Pokémon, unzips the file, and uses `sprintf()` to build the path names to read each file.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/PokemonXLSX.zip",
               "PokemonXLSX.zip",
               method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("PokemonXLSX.zip")
library(readxl)
# create a set of numbers to be used to generate file names
# that have leading zeros, e.g. gen01.xlsx, gen02.xlsx, etc. 
generationIds <- 1:7
spreadsheets <- lapply(generationIds,function(x) {
     # use generation number to create individual file name
     aFile <- sprintf("./PokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx",x)
     data <- read_excel(aFile)
     })
```

In order to merge the files by an ID variable, one can use the `Reduce()` function as illustrated in another answer.

The following code illustrates how the file names are created.

```
theFiles <- lapply(generationIds,function(x) {
        # use generation number to create individual file name
        aFile <- sprintf("./PokemonData/gen%02i.xlsx",x)
        message(paste("current file is: ",aFile))
        aFile
})
```